# Strange behavior of update query teradata

Tags: sql, sql-update, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Below query updated the columns that are not mentioned in the set statement. Is anything wrong with the query?

Thanks in advance.

```
UPDATE EDW1
   FROM
    TABLE1  EDW1, ( SELECT EDW2.A ,  EDW2.B,    EDW2.C,     EDW3.D,     EDW3.E , EDW3.F
    FROM TABLE2  EDW2 LEFT JOIN  TABLE3 EDW3 ON
                                               EDW2.X =EDW3.X )  EDW4
       SET
        product_name= EDW4.B
       ,revenue_type= EDW4.C
       ,product_type = EDW4.D
       ,product_category= EDW4.E
       ,product_family= EDW4.F    WHERE  EDW1.A= EDW4.A;
```

Comment: Can you proof that this happened? Can you repeat it?

Comment: yes, I found the issue by running the update statement again on the backup that I have taken and found the non mentioned column also has been updated(which was the issue). 
Did it a couple of time more just to make sure.

Comment: This would be a severe bug, you should open an incident with Teradata support.

Answer (score 1):

As per your example only the following columns would be updated.

```
product_name = EDW4.B
revenue_type = EDW4.C
product_type = EDW4.D
product_category = EDW4.E
product_family = EDW4.F
```

- My guess is there is a trigger on the table that does updates
- There is a job or program that is monitoring and performing maintenance
- The database has some kind of audit trail enabled which makes updates
- Somebody else is making changes at the same time

So to answer your question, your query will only update those tables listed.  If you have a dev area you can test in, you could try:

- To use a profiling tool to see what other query has run immediately after yours completes.
- Just update one column very simply, do you see this behavior?  Then narrow down to what is causing this

By the way, my money is on a trigger :)

Comment: The probability for a trigger in a Data Warehouse is quite low. @TARUNJOSHI: When you Explain your Update you would see the trigger executing.

Comment: @dnoeth No, there was no trigger executing, I again executed in the test environment and resulted in the same way. 
updating one column at a time to find the issue.